# Connecting Two Monitors to Acer Aspire 5742-6638

Tags: windows-7

I'm currently connecting my Acer Aspire 5742-6638 to an external VGA port.  The laptop also has a HDMI port.  I would like to get an additional monitor with the HDMI input to hookup to the laptop, if possible.  This way, I would have three displays.

Will the Acer Aspire 5742-6638 (CPU - Core i5) support the arrangement?  I like to know before going out buying the additional display.

Answer (score 1):

A [Mobile Core i5](http://ark.intel.com/products/52952/Intel-Core-i5-480M-Processor-%283M-Cache-2_66-GHz%29) can only support 2 displays, so no you couldn't add a third display.

The VGA port may work at the same time as the HDMI, but if it did it would definitely disable the laptop's LCD.  The only option I know of for adding a third display is a USB video adapter.